# Как получить местное время из серверного?

Tags: c#

На локальной машине функция `DateTime.Now.ToString()` дает результат

> 27.06.2016 15:27:55

, а при развертывании на сервер

> 6/28/2016 1:14:55 AM

Как привести второй вариант в первому? Желательно без разбора строк.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-ru"))
```

Класс `CultureInfo` находится в пространстве имен `System.Globalization`.

Если получение строкового представления даты вызывается многократно в разных местах, и каждый раз явно указывать язык неудобно, то можно установить локаль в рамках всего треда:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-ru");
```

---

Если сервер находится в другом часовом поясе, а дату нужно получить, например, по московскому времени, то воспользуйтесь классом `TimeZoneInfo`:

```
static string GetCurrentDateTime()
{
    var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Russian Standard Time");
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, tz)
            .ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-ru"));
}
```

Список идентификаторов часовых поясов можно получить, вызвав `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()`.